# Validation failed: Cast to Array failed for value

Tags: typescript, mongoose, nestjs, typegraphql, typegoose

I am trying to use Typegoose with GrqphQL, MongoDB and Nest.js. I wanted to create a mutation which will create a post. I created model, service and resolver for simple *Post*. When I am trying to run my mutation to create a Post I am getting this error:

> PostModel validation failed: sections: Cast to Array failed for value:
>
> ```
> [
>   [Object: null prototype] {
>     title: 'section 1',
>     body: [ 'section test lalal' ],
>     code: [ "console.log('hello world!)" ],
>     image: [ 'kanow.svg' ]
>   }
> ]
> ```
>
> at path "sections"

I do not know why I am getting this error I tried to use: **ref**, **itemsRefs** (for class and string value. You can read more about this here: [typegoose arrayProp](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/decorators/arrayProp/)).  After I create new `PostModel` and I `console.log` every property I can see that `sections` is an empty array, but it shouldn't, because inside `postInput` I can find this JSON:

```
[Object: null prototype] {
  title: 'refactored post',
  image: 'rest.jpg',
  tags: [ 'ref, ref' ],
  sections: [
    [Object: null prototype] {
      title: 'section 1',
      body: [Array],
      code: [Array],
      image: [Array]
    }
  ]
}
```

I think this json looks good so it shouldn't be a source of this error.

I want to know what I am doing wrong and why it is not working. Below I attached some code. If you need anything else let me know in comments.

**GraphQL mutation**:

```
mutation {
  createPost(postInput: {
    image: "rest.jpg",
    title: "refactored post"
    tags: ["ref, ref"]
    sections: [{
      title: "section 1"
      body: ["section test lalal"]
      code: ["console.log('hello world!)"]
      image: ["kanow.svg"]
    }]
  }) {
    _id
    title
    tags
    sections {
      title
      body
      code
      image
    }
  }
}
```

**post.service.ts**:

```js
@Injectable()
export class PostsService {
    constructor(@InjectModel(PostModel) private readonly postModel: ReturnModelType<typeof PostModel>) {
    }

    async create(postInput: CreatePostInput): Promise<DocumentType<PostModel>> {
        const createdPost: DocumentType<PostModel> = new this.postModel(postInput);
        return await createdPost.save();
    }
 ...
}
```

**post.model.ts**:

```js
@ObjectType()
export class PostModel {
    @Field(() => ID)
    readonly _id: ObjectId;

    @Field()
    @prop({required: true})
    title: string;

    @Field()
    @prop({nullable: true})
    image: string;

    @Field(() => [String])
    @arrayProp({items: String})
    tags: string[];

    @Field(() => [SectionModel])
    @arrayProp({ref: 'SectionModel'})
    sections: Ref<SectionModel>[];
}
```

**section.model.ts**:

```js
@ObjectType()
export class SectionModel {
  @Field()
  @prop({ required: true })
  title: string;

  @Field(() => [String])
  @arrayProp({ items: String })
  body: string[];

  @Field(() => [String])
  @arrayProp({ items: String })
  code: string[];

  @Field(() => [String])
  @arrayProp({ items: String })
  image: string[];
}
```

**create-post.input.ts**:

```js
@InputType()
export class CreatePostInput {
  @Field()
  readonly title!: string;

  @Field()
  readonly image!: string;

  @Field(() => [String])
  readonly tags!: string[];

  @Field(() => [CreateSectionInput])
  readonly sections!: CreateSectionInput[];
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

I discovered that if I pass an empty array inside sections body then there is no problem to create a post. I attach example query below:

```
mutation {
  createPost(postInput: {
    image: "newly created.jpg",
    title: "newly created"
    tags: ["newly created, ref"]
    sections: []
  }) {
    _id
    image
    title
    tags
    sections {
      title
      body
      code
      image
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I should not use `Ref<>` for declaring nested documents. To do it you have to use **items** and provide correct typgoose model class. In the documentation you can read that [**items**](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/decorators/arrayProp/#items) are only for primitive types but in the end of **items** documentation description you can read that you can use it also for **typegoose** classes (for example `SectionModel.ts`). Below I attached an example which is solving my problem.

**post.model.ts:**

```js
@ObjectType()
export class PostModel {
  @Field(() => ID)
  readonly _id: ObjectId;

  @Field()
  @prop({required: true})
  title: string;

  @Field()
  @prop({nullable: true})
  image: string;

  @Field(() => [String])
  @arrayProp({items: String})
  tags: string[];

  @Field(() => [SectionModel])
  @arrayProp({items: SectionModel})
  sections: SectionModel[];
}
```

**section.model.ts:**

```js
@ObjectType()
export class SectionModel {
  @Field(() => ID)
  readonly _id: ObjectId;

  @Field()
  @prop({ required: true })
  title: string;

  @Field(() => [String])
  @arrayProp({ items: String })
  body: string[];

  @Field(() => [String])
  @arrayProp({ items: String })
  code: string[];

  @Field(() => [String])
  @arrayProp({ items: String })
  image: string[];
}
```